# Javascript menu changer

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I have tried making a menu in javascript that changes the name, description and image of the 8 different menu items. As of yesterday it worked but something happened and now it doesn't work. I asked my teacher and she doesnt know whats wrong either.

```js
function menytema1() {
    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    var title = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-button")
    var description = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-body")
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        let images = cards[i].getElementsByTagName("img");
        title[i].innerHTML = "En typ av Pizza";
        description[i].innerHTML = "Beskriving av Pizzan"
        for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
            images[index].src = "../img/pizza_card.jpg"
        }

    }

}
function menytema2() {
    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    var title = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-button")
    var description = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-body")
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        let images = cards[i].getElementsByTagName("img");
        title[i].innerHTML = "En sorts Kebab";
        description[i].innerHTML = "Beskriving av Kebaben"
        for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
            images[index].src = "../img/kebab_card.jpg"
        }

    }

}
function menytema3() {
    var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    var title = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-button")
    var description = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-body")
    for (i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        let images = cards[i].getElementsByTagName("img");
        title[i].innerHTML = "En variant av Gyros";
        description[i].innerHTML = "Beskriving av Gyros"
        for (let index = 0; index < images.length; index++) {
            images[index].src = "../img/gyros_card.jpg"
        }

    }

}
```

```css
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
      color: white;
      font-size: 3vh;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
      color: red;
    }

    #logoname {
      margin-left: 1vh;
      font-size: x-large;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: white;
    }

    .opentimes {
      font-size: large;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link a {
      color: white;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: rgb(182, 172, 172)
    }

    .body {
      background-color: rgb(83, 82, 82);
    }

    .meny-item a:hover {
      color: red;
    }

    .meny-item .food-name a {
      color: black;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #1f1f1f;
    }

    .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .accordion-button {
      color: white;
    }

    .accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
      filter: brightness(0%) invert(100%);
    }

    .accordion-button.collapsed::after {
      filter: brightness(0%) invert(100%);
    }

    .accordion-button:focus {
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    .accordion-body {
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

    .box {
      margin-top: 15vh;
      margin-bottom: 5vh;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Korvens Pizzeria</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
    integrity="sha384-ejwKkLla8gPP8t2u0eQyL0Q/4ItcnyveF505U0NIobD/SMsNyXrLti6CWaD0L52l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="../script/script.js"></script>
  <style>
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
      color: white;
      font-size: 3vh;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
      color: red;
    }

    #logoname {
      margin-left: 1vh;
      font-size: x-large;
      font-weight: 600;
      color: white;
    }

    .opentimes {
      font-size: large;
      font-weight: 700;
    }

    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link a {
      color: white;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: rgb(182, 172, 172)
    }

    .body {
      background-color: rgb(83, 82, 82);
    }

    .meny-item a:hover {
      color: red;
    }

    .meny-item .food-name a {
      color: black;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #1f1f1f;
    }

    .accordion-button:not(.collapsed) {
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .accordion-button {
      color: white;
    }

    .accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
      filter: brightness(0%) invert(100%);
    }

    .accordion-button.collapsed::after {
      filter: brightness(0%) invert(100%);
    }

    .accordion-button:focus {
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    .accordion-body {
      border-radius: 0.25rem;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    }

    .box {
      margin-top: 15vh;
      margin-bottom: 5vh;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark p-3">
    <div class="container">
      <p id="logoname">Korvens <span class="text-danger">Pizzeria</span></p>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
        aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <div class="mx-auto"></div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Hem</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Meny</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="kontakt.html" class="nav-link">Kontakt</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="om_oss.html" class="nav-link">Om Oss</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class="box">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center g-4">
        <div class="col-md">
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-3 text-danger">
              Meny
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="p-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center g-4">
        <div class="col-md">
          <div class="card bg-dark"></div>
          <div class="card-body text-center">
            <h3 class="card-title mb-3 text-light">
              Korvens Pizzeria
            </h3>
            <p class="card-text text-light">
              All våran mat är lagad med kärlek
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" id="pizza-knapp" onclick="menytema1()">Pizza</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" id="kebab-knapp" onclick="menytema2()">Kebab</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" id="gyros-knapp" onclick="menytema3()">Gyros</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row text-center g-4">
        <!-- menu-item 1 -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body bg-dark">
              <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                      data-bs-target="#menuitem-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                      En typ av Pizza
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="menuitem-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- menu-item 2 -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body bg-dark">
              <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                      data-bs-target="#menuitem-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                      En typ av Pizza
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="menuitem-2" class="accordion-collapse collapse multi-collapse"
                    aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- meny-item 3 -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body bg-dark">
              <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                      data-bs-target="#menuitem-3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                      En typ av Pizza
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="menuitem-3" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ment-item 4 -->
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body bg-dark">
              <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                <div class="accordion-item">
                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                    <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                      data-bs-target="#menuitem-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                      En typ av Pizza
                    </button>
                  </h2>
                  <div id="menuitem-4" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                    <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center g-4">
          <!-- menu-item 5 -->
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
              <div class="card-body bg-dark">
                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                  <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                      <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#menuitem-5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                        En typ av Pizza
                      </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="menuitem-5" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                      <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- menu-item 6-->
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
              <div class="card-body bg-dark">
                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                  <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                      <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#menuitem-6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                        En typ av Pizza
                      </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="menuitem-6" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                      <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- menu-item 7-->
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
              <div class="card-body bg-dark">
                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                  <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                      <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#menuitem-7" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                        En typ av Pizza
                      </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="menuitem-7" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                      <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- menu-item 8 -->
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="../img/pizza_card.jpg" alt="Pizza" class="card-img-top">
              <div class="card-body bg-dark">
                <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
                  <div class="accordion-item">
                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
                      <button class="accordion-button collapsed bg-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                        data-bs-target="#menuitem-8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Öppna salads meny">
                        En typ av Pizza
                      </button>
                    </h2>
                    <div id="menuitem-8" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne">
                      <div class="accordion-body">Beskriving av Pizzan</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row text-center g-4">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var nav = document.querySelector('nav');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 15) {
        nav.classList.add('bg-dark', 'shadow');
      } else {
        nav.classList.remove('bg-dark', 'shadow');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Did you look in the console for errors?  (or even run your snippet which shows the console errors?)  `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')` looks like something that can be at least considered

Comment: Add some *basic* debugging (your teacher should have started you here): `console.log(cards.length, title.length, description.length)` inside the click handler after the doc.getElements.   Result:  9, 8, 8 -  clearly you have more elements with class `card` than you do cards with titles/descriptions

Comment: Quick look in the html and you have `<div class="card bg-dark"></div>` without a title/description, it's just above "Korvens Pizzeria".  Remove that div (as it doesn't seem to do anything) and you're back to being ok: https://jsfiddle.net/Ltj8cxuk/1/

Comment: Thank you for your help. Bit of an obvious problem, but hey you learn from your mistakes.